# Is $S^1\vee S^1$ an Eilenberg-Mac Lane Space to a Homotopy Purist?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I believe that $S^1\vee S^1$ is the Eilenberg-Mac Lane space $K(\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z},1)$. One can prove this by constructing its universal cover and observing that it is contractible.

My question is this:

**Is there a simple homotopy-theoretic proof of this result that does not use connected covers?**

I have never seen one appear in any text. Repeated attemps by myself to use the usual tools (Hilton-Milnor Theorem, examine the fibre of the inclusion $S^1\vee S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\times S^1$, etc...) to prove this elementary result have met with connectivity issues or similar problems.

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of answer you're after. Presumably such a proof would take as input that a circle is a K(Z,1). But how do you prove that without mentioning covering spaces?

Comment: That said, given that the circle is K(Z,1), maybe you can use the higher van Kampen spectral sequence.

Comment: I'm want to assume known that $S^1$ is the E-M space $K(\mathcal{Z},1)$. From here I want to form the wedge $S^1\vee S^1$ and unveil its homotopy properties. I just want to know if it can be done without using covering spaces.

Comment: I think that a homotopy purist would first want to formulate the question as follows: If $X$ is a K($G$, 1) and $Y$ is a $K($H$, 1)$, is $X\vee Y$ a K($G*H$, 1)?  This is true, but I don't know how to prove it without using universal covering spaces.  Searching around a little on Google, I didn't find any discussion of this fact, apart from one paper stating it without proof.  But maybe I haven't looked hard enough.

Comment: @DanRamras, that was mainly my motivation in asking the question. I've seen various references to it but have never actually seen a proof of the statement. It seems to be a little bit of mathematical folklore.

Comment: Here is a sketch proof: Fix basepoints  $x_0 \in X$ and $y_0 \in Y$ (and form the wedge using these basepoints).  The universal cover of $X\vee Y$ can be built by taking a copy of the universal cover $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ and glueing on a copy of the universal cover $\tilde{Y}$ of $Y$ at every point in the inverse image of $x_0$, and then glueing on a copy of $\tilde{X}$ at all points in the inverse image of $y_0$, continuing ad infinitum.  Take the colimit of the various stages of the construction; any map from a compact set into it lands in a finite stage, which is contractible by induction.

Comment: Maybe a homotopy purist would say that there's nothing very homotopically pure about the fundamental group (e.g. it's nonabelian), and hence we shouldn't expect this to follow from very general homotopical considerations.  Or maybe one will come along with a nice proof!

Comment: I also wish I knew how to prove this without using covering spaces. The most general fact I know about things being unexpectedly 1-types is that if you have a functor $F$ from the free category on a directed graph $G$ to the category of groups and **injective** group homomorphisms, then the homotopy colimit of the classifying spaces of those group, $\mathrm{hocolim}_{x \in G} BF(x)$, is a 1-type. This is Theorem 1B.11 in Hatcher's Topology. (The proof builds the universal cover of the colimit.)

Comment: Note that that result becomes false if you remove almost any hypothesis:  (1) remove injective, (2) take arbitrary categories as the diagram shape (in place of free ones), or (3) instead of $BF(x)$ which is a connected 1-type, take the homotopy colimit of arbitrary 1-types. And it's badly false in those three cases, in the sense that you get non truncated spaces like $S^2$ as the result.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena When I was writing my comment above, I felt sure it ought to be somewhere in Hatcher's book.  Thanks for reminding me where it is!

Comment: Another textbook reference for the result mentioned by Omar (which also uses covering spaces) is Theorem 7.1.9 of *Topological methods in group theory* by Ross Geoghegan.

Comment: I mildly object to the insinuation that a pure homotopy theorist wouldn't like the universal cover approach. I mean here you don't need the universal cover up to homeomorphism, only up to homotopy equivalence. That's certainly pure homotopy theory: if $X$ is connected, the universal cover of $X$ has the homotopy type of the homotopy fibre of the canonical map $X \to \tau_{\le 1} X$. Jesse's Ans 1 shows how to prove that this fibre is contractible without using covering space theory.

Comment: A *geometric* topologist can see that $X=S^1\vee S^1$ is aspherical without passing to universal covers by working directly with maps of spheres. A map $f:S^n\to X$ can be homotoped to be transverse to the midpoints of edges. The preimage of these midpoints is then a submanifold $T$ of $S^n$ which decomposes $S^n$ into open regions. Since $S^n$ is simply connected, the dual graph of this decomposition is a tree, which therefore has a leaf. Therefore some region $U$ is bounded by just one component $T_0$ of $T$. It follows that $f$ can be homotoped to remove $T_0$, and we conclude by induction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following can be turned into a proof, but I haven't checked the details.

By a result of Milnor, $\Omega (S^1 \vee S^1)$ coincides up to homotopy with $F(S^0 \vee S^0)$, the free group functor on the pointed set $S^0 \vee S^0$. By a version of the Hilton-Milnor theorem, the latter coincides up to homotopy with $F(S^0) \ast F(S^0)$, the latter being the free
product with amalgamation of simplicial free groups. But $F(S^0)$ coincides with $\Bbb Z$ up to homotopy. Hence, 
$\Omega (S^1 \vee S^1)$ coincides up to homotopy with $\Bbb Z \ast \Bbb Z$ (as a space). In particular, $\Omega (S^1 \vee S^1)$ is homotopically discrete, which gives the result you are after (in conjunction with the van Kampen theorem).

Comment: Have you got a reference for Milnor's result?

Comment: It appears in

Adams, John Frank Algebraic topology—a student's guide. London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, No. 4. Cambridge University Press, London-New York, 1972

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer. The inclusion of homotopy $1$-types into homotopy types has a left adjoint $\tau_{\le 1}$ given by truncation, and hence preserves homotopy limits (e.g. products). The question at hand is whether there is a homotopy-theoretic way to see that it also preserves certain homotopy colimits, namely a certain shape of homotopy pushout.

One might ask more generally what happens when $1$ is replaced by $n$, and here I believe it's not true that the inclusion of homotopy $n$-types preserves homotopy pushouts; e.g. I don't believe it's true that the wedge sum of two homotopy $n$-types is another homotopy $n$-type. (The first counterexample that comes to mind only works rationally: rationally $S^2$ is a $2$-type, but $S^2 \vee S^2$ has rational homotopy in arbitrarily high degrees.)

So there's something special about the inclusion of homotopy $1$-types. At this point you might be happy to learn that it's possible to develop covering space theory for groupoids without any reference to topological spaces. I think this is already enough to prove the desired result, by a construction, at the level of groupoids, of the universal cover of $BG \vee BH$. In fact it ought to be possible to completely describe the covering theory of $BG \vee BH$ at the level of groupoids, leading to the [Kurosh subgroup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurosh_subgroup_theorem). For some indication of how this might be done see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/drawing-subgroups-of-the-modular-group/), which has some pictures of the special case $G = C_2, H = C_3$.

Comment: The most general homotopy colimit I know that $\tau_{\le 1}$ preserves is given by Theorem 1B.11 in Hatcher's book. It gives you that $\mathrm{hocolim} BF$ is a 1-type if $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Groups}$ is a diagram of groups and **injective** group homomorphisms and $\mathcal{C}$ is the free category on a directed graph.

Comment: @Omar: I know an example not covered by that statement; the inclusion of $1$-types (not $\tau_{\le 1}$, which is its left adjoint) also preserves homotopy quotients by (discrete) group actions.

Comment: In fact we always have $\pi_{2n-1}(K(A,n) \vee K(B,n)) = A \otimes B$ for $n > 1$, and so this is often not an $n$-type. Something genuinely special is happening in the case $n=1$.

Comment: A groupoid proof of the Kurosh subgroup theorem is in Philip Higgins' 1971  book "Categories and Groupoids"  available at http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html . Philip told me he thought of the use of groupoids when reading Hilton and Wylie's account of covering spaces.

Answer (score 3):

$\renewcommand{\deloop}{\mathbf{B}}\renewcommand{\sph}{\mathbb{S}} $

**Ans 1**: Calculate the homotopy fiber of the map $\sph^1\vee \sph^1\to \deloop F_2$ classifying the generators.  This (by distributivity/Mather's Cube Theorems) is the pushout of the two maps $\langle x,y\rangle \to \langle x,y\rangle/\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle x,y\rangle \to \langle x,y\rangle/\langle y\rangle$; that this pushout is contractible boils down to the combinatorial exercise that a word in $\{ x,y \}$  knows what its letters are.  (If you like, this is the homotopy reason for the connected cover story; it may also be what Qiaochu is getting at, but I'm not quite sure I can tell for sure)

**Ans 2**: The loopspace functor $\Omega$ from connected pointed spaces $\mathrm{Top}_{0,*}$ to (tame-enough) grouplike $A_\infty$-spaces has a homotopy  inverse $\mathbf{B}$.

In particular, $\deloop$ sends colimits to colimits, and $\deloop\mathbb{Z}\simeq\sph^1$.

---

Ans 2 may sound fancier than Ans 1, but they're actually built from the same tools.

Comment: For Ans 2, how do you show that the coproduct of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ in grouplike $A_\infty$-spaces? I know it's the coproduct in groups (or even monoids), can that statement be reduced to this one somehow?

Comment: Right, Omar's question is the reason this isn't a formal exercise (at least as far as I can see). Analogously to my answer, the inclusion of groups into grouplike $E_1$ spaces has a left adjoint given by $\pi_0$, so it preserves homotopy limits for formal reasons, but the question at hand is why it preserves a certain homotopy colimit.

Comment: The spaces in the $A_\infty$-operad are contractible?
~~~~
Or, what happens if I say: let $G$ and $H$ be simplicial groups, and define $(G * H)_k = (G_k) * (H_k)$ with faces/degeneracies defined extending $G_k \to G_{k\pm 1} \to (G * H)_{k\pm 1} $ ... (which are therefore simplicial groups again)?
~~~~
Good questions, of course.  Will get back to you.

Comment: $A_\infty$ spaces can be strictified.  So when both exist in the right category, the $A_\infty$-colimit is a competitor, in groups, to the group colimit, and the group colimit is a competitor, in $A_\infty$-spaces, to the $A_\infty$-colimit.  Composing comparison maps on both sides et.c.

Comment: I like your Ans 1! Although I have to say it felt very much like building the universal cover and observing it's a tree. What I mean is that the only way I saw to show the contractibility of the homotopy pushout of discrete spaces $F_2/\langle x\rangle \leftarrow F_2 \rightarrow F_2/\langle y \rangle$ is to prove that the usual double mapping cylinder construction of the homotopy pushout is a tree.

Comment: Well, effectively, yes, it would have to be the universal cover construction, in the end (what else *is* a contractible fibration over a graph?); but the point is we don't have to *say* "universal cover" or remember a recipe for building it.

Comment: Well, sure @JesseC.McKeown: the homotopy fiber of the map $S^1 \vee S^1 \to BF_2$ has the homotopy type of the universal cover, so this proof is secretely about universal covers. What I meant is that even though you avoid having to mention covering space theory, the only way I figured out how to finish your argument is by building a model of the universal cover and showing it's a tree. So the meat seems the same and I was hoping maybe it wouldn't.

Comment: This is essentially the true reason. Considering the genuinely special $n=1$ thing in Tyler Lawson's comment in another answer, we similarly have that pointed $n-1$-connected spaces are equivalent to $E_n$-groups. Under this equivalence $K(A, n)$ is the discrete space $A$ with obvious $E_n$-group structure coming from abelian group structure. The equivalence tells us that $K(A,n)\vee K(B,n)$ is also $n$-connected and its $n$-fold loop space is the free product of $E_n$-groups $A$ and $B$. But a free product of $E_n$-groups is not discrete: already the free $E_n$-group  $\Omega^n S^n$ isn't.